# Print all sub directories (include directories that starts with ".")

Tags: linux

I need to print the full path of directories and all sub directories under some source directory

For example, how do I print all directories/sub directories under /etc or /var .. (include directory that start with dot ".")?

Example of printing

```
/etc/rc0.d
/etc/rc1.d
/etc/rc2.d
/etc/rc3.d
/etc/rc4.d
/etc/rc5.d
/etc/rc6.d
/etc/.test.dir
/etc/xd1/menus/preferences-merged
/etc/xd2/menus/applications-merged
/etc/xd3/menus/preferences-post-merged
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find <some path> -type d
```

Comment: hi I have littlie problem if for example /var -> /var/newdir/dir then find command cant find the subdirectories (because /var is linked to /var/newdir/dir

Comment: `/var` -> `/var/newdir/dir` seems to me a quite strange linkage, but you should use `-L` option to make `find` follows symbolic links.

Comment: my linux not support the -L option so I  write:    find /var -type l -type d (something wrong with this ?)

Comment: @jennifer: You can add a slash at the end of the argument to make `find` follow a symbolic link on the starting path, e.g., `find /var/ -type d`.

Comment: @jennifer to do symlinks, `find` has the `-follow` flag.  `find /var -follow -type d`

Answer (score 0):

`tree` will do it. To include '.dotfiles' `-a`, to show full path for each file `-f`:

```
tree -af
```

and if you do not like indentation:

```
tree -afi
```

Comment: find has the advantage that it's always installed whereas tree needs to be installed manually on most distributions.